# Does kineticjs provide attribute Selector?

Tags: kineticjs

Does kineticjs provide attributeSelector?

I have a number of Kinetic shapes which contains same name. Some of the shapes contain a custom attribute suppose "userType". Can I filter based on "useType" from the given shapes using kineticjs instead of doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS has a `myContainer.getChildren(fn)` method that lets you specify a function used to fetch a collection of children from a container.

**For example, if you have added these Circle objects to the layer:**

```
// add 3 Circles with attribute 'userType==pickMe!'

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    var c=new Kinetic.Circle({id:i,x:50,y:50+i*40,radius:15,fill:"red"});
    c.setAttr('userType','pickMe!');
    layer.add(c);
}

// add 1 circle with attribute 'userType==dontPickMe.'

var c=new Kinetic.Circle({id:i,x:50,y:170,radius:15,fill:"blue"});
c.setAttr('userType','dontPickMe.');
layer.add(c);
```

**Then you can use `layer.getChildren` to fetch the elements with 'userType==pickMe!'**

```
// `var found` will contain the 3 Circles with 'userType==pickMe!'

var found=layer.getChildren(function(node){
    return(node.getAttr('userType')=='pickMe!');
});
```